# http server is running but receiving 404 while using with timer

Tags: http, go, socket.io

i am running below code block to run http server on localhost:

```
server, err := socketio.NewServer(nil)
.
.
.
go server.Serve()
defer server.Close()

router.Handle("/socket.io/", server)

log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, router))
```

and before this code i am calling initTimer method in the `main` function. Here is `initTimer` method:

```
func initTimer() {

    stop := time.After(3 * time.Second)
    for {
        select {
        case <-stop:
            fmt.Println("EXIT: 3 seconds")
        case <-time.After(10 * time.Second):
            println("ali")

}
```

i don't receive any error and http server is running as expected. But when i send request from postman i am facing 404 error. when i remove initTimer method everything running as excepted and it returns 200. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Can you post a little more of your HTTP code? You have to understand that HanderFuncs that are registered with your `router` are executed in their own Goroutines, so things like timers that are outside of them have to communicate over channels, or some other way.

Comment: @jcdl there is no more code :( i am just setting to http paths and using it in the gorillamux router to run http server.

Comment: Are you trying to delay each request or the just the start of your http server?

Comment: @jcdl İ am just starting http server. The timer isn't related with http requests

Comment: The above function as listed would have zero-effect on another goroutine i.e. a `http.Server`. You need to post more of your router/server setup.

Comment: @colm.anseo i posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you want to run your timer function independent of the http server, simply start it in its own goroutine:

```
go initTimer()
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, router))
```

Comment: its working but now case <-time.After(10 * time.Second) only triggering one time. how to fix it?

Comment: @Ali Gürelli try using ticker https://golang.org/pkg/time/#NewTicker

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop you posted will never terminate. Once of your `switch` cases needs to `break` out of the for loop. If you do not break out of the `for` loop, your call to `http.ListenAndServe` will never run.

Comment: i can't use it out of the for loop. when i try this the ide giving error. Also when i put break inside of switch-case it still don't works

Comment: From the Go [http docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServe): `ListenAndServe always returns a non-nil error.` The "cleanest" error it will return, if there's no port-in-use, or bad TLS cert config etc. is `ErrServerClosed` after a `http.Server.Shutdown()`.

Comment: Whoops! Of course, ListenAndServe will block the main goroutine!

Comment: so what should i do to run timer

Comment: @AliGürelli You would need to run it in its own goroutine. https://gobyexample.com/goroutines